# PHP Manager for IIS fails to install

Tags: php, windows-10, web-platform-installer, php-manager

I am trying to install PHP on IIS 8.

Every time I start the PHP installation, PHP installs but I get the follow error:

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look in the installer logs. Without knowing what's in there it's kinda hard to help you.

Comment: This is all very confusing. You asked this question in January 2014, and mention IIS 8. The current two top-voted answers, including the one you have accepted as the answer, are based on Windows 10, which was released a year and a half later. And someone has edited your tags to add Windows 10. I'm confused ...

Comment: @RenniePet maybe because this open source tool has been abandoned too long, so from IIS 8 to IIS 10 it is always problematic. I created a new repo to fully take over the project, and its 2.0 release is on the way https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1

Comment: Anyone else gets this `Signature verification failed on downloaded file.`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As Abhi says: fire up regedit.exe and change the decimal value of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters\MajorVersion` from 10 (as set by Windows 10) to e.g. 8. Installer should work now. Afterwards, you can set the value back to 10 (or whatever value your Windows env. had at first).

**Tip**: For quick navigation, paste the path `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters`into the address-bar of Registry Editor and hit Enter.

Also, for me on Windows 10, I had to enable `.NET Framework 3.5` > `Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation`for the installer to progress. Without this enabled, installer would just hang at step 1. Requires reboot.

Comment: Worked for me! didn't have to enable .NET fw 3.5 ...
thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, this is mentioned in this [MS Answers page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8) which links to the issue on [PHP Manager's Codeplex](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/workitem/2653)

Comment: Thanks a lot Frederik

Comment: It's almost 2018 and Microsoft has yet to fix. They must hate php on windows.

Comment: This answer worked for me heres a video tut explaining the same thing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgniQdb2lWE

Comment: @MH PHP Manager for IIS is not a "Microsoft product", but a community open source project.

Comment: I created a new repo to fully take over the project, and its 2.0 release is on the way https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1

Comment: to complement the WCF http activation is under appwiz.cpl ((un)install programs) -> turn windows features on or off ->

Answer (score 31):

Installation of PHP Manager for IIS via the Web Platform Installer requires .NET 3.5 to work properly.  Install .NET 3.5 first, and you should be all set.

Comment: .net 3.5 is already installed but the PHP manager install still fails on Windows server 2016.

Answer (score 27):

The setup program checks that the registry value HKLM/System/CCS/Services/W3SVC/Parameters/MajorVersion is >= 7. The value in the registry is 0xA, which I am assuming is the problem. For a workaround, change the registry value to 9 (or 8 or 7) and PHP Manager for IIS should install correctly. [insert standard disclaimer about editing the registry]

Comment: This fixed my Windows 10 problem.  Already had .NET installed.

Answer (score 13):

Currently the installation also fails in case of using the Web Platform Installer because the Codeplex download link used by the Web Platform Installer does not exist anymore.

Luckily some guys created GitHub repositories to update PHP Manager. These repositories provide new releases witch should work without the registry hack.

The MSI installer can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases

https://github.com/RonaldCarter/PHPManager/releases

Comment: There is a newer repo to fully take over the project, https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1