# PHP Manager IIS fails to install Windows 10

Tags: php, iis, windows-10, php-manager

I have recently installed windows 10 from windows 8 and i'm trying to get my IIS setup to create a wordpress site. To be honest i have no idea what any of this means:

```
MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:773]: Skipping action: ERRCA_CANCELNEWERVERSION (condition is false)
MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:773]: Doing action: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions
Action ended 16:13:26: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:774]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4:    SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions' 
MSI (s) (F8:E8) [16:13:26:776]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI5B2B.tmp, Entrypoint: VsdLaunchConditions
Action start 16:13:26: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions.
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:778] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:778] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:779] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Enumerating table using SQL statement: 'SELECT * FROM `_VsdLaunchCondition`'
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:780] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Calling MsiGetActiveDatabase...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:781] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiDatabaseOpenViewW - Prepare Database to view table...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:781] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: TMsiViewExecute - Open Database view on table...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:782] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:782] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:782] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:783] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:783] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Evaluating condition 'VersionNT64'...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:784] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: RESULT:  Condition is true. Nothing more to do.
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:785] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:785] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:785] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:786] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:786] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Evaluating condition 'IISREGISTRYVALUE >= "#7"'...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:787] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: RESULT:  Condition is false.
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:787] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:787] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '2'...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:788] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
MSI (s) (F8!14) [16:13:26:789]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding HideFatalErrorForm property. Its value is 'TRUE'.
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:789] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'HideFatalErrorForm' to 'TRUE'.
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:789] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:790] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: A launch condition has already fired. My work is done here.
ERROR  : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:790] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action failed with code: '1603'
INFO   : [05/02/2016 16:13:26:791] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '1603'
CustomAction VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 16:13:26: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 16:13:26: INSTALL. Return value 3.
 MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:794]: Note: 1: 1708 
 MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:794]: Product: PHP Manager 1.2 for IIS 7 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:794]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: PHP Manager 1.2 for IIS 7. Product Version: 1.2.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: . Installation success or error status: 1603.

 MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:796]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
 MSI (s) (F8:A0) [16:13:26:796]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
 MSI (s) (F8:98) [16:13:26:798]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
 MSI (s) (F8:98) [16:13:26:798]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
```

I can only assume that this part  CustomAction VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions returned actual error code 1603  is what is causing me the issue.

In which case i've found this https://forums.iis.net/t/1207407.aspx
And .net 3.5 is installed and enabled, so i have no idea where to go from here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Manager for IIS fails to install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216228/php-manager-for-iis-fails-to-install)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like the installer is failing when checking the IIS version.

The following Microsoft Answers page suggests some registry hacking might solve the problem..

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Comment: Dint work for me. (Windows 10, PHP 7, IIS 10)
Changed the HKLM../.././MajorVersion value to 9(8 as well). Post this, tried installing PHP manager from Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0, but same error:Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with...

Comment: @AshishGoyal you hit another issue, and you might try the 2.0 installers https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1

Answer (score 5):

For full reference from the article [mentioned in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986107/1037948):

Change the value of the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters\MajorVersion
```

> The value is 10 (Ax0). Just change the value to 9 (or 8), then try to
>   install it again. To avoid future issues with other IIS stuff, change
>   back to 10 (Ax0). It seems that PHP Manager validates the value...Here is the issue from PHP Manager's website https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/workitem/2653

(via [Microsoft Answers page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8))

Comment: Ax0? Is that big-endian for 0xA?  :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me on WIndows Server 2012. The value is already 0x09, installer still fails

Answer (score 0):

Currently the installation also fails in case of using the Web Platform Installer because the Codeplex download link used by the Web Platform Installer does not exist anymore.

Luckily someone created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RonaldCarter/PHPManager) to update PHP Manager. The repository provides some new releases witch should work without the registry hack.

The MSI installer can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/RonaldCarter/PHPManager/releases

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012 R2 none of the Web Platform Installers worked for me. They either threw errors during the installation or they installed obsolete versions of PHP with no native drivers for connecting to the MySql server. What worked for me was installing PHP Manager [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10) from MS and then pointing it to php-cgi.exe contained in the folder of PHP 7.0 which I downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinstallermsi/files/zip/php-7.0.21-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip/download) from sourceforge.