# PHP Manager IIS fails to install on Windows Server 2016

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2016, php-manager

I have recently installed Windows Server 2016 and I'm trying to get my IIS 10 set-up to create a site.
The PHP 5.6.30 installed just fine, but the *PHP Manager 1.2*, *WinCache 1.3 for PHP 5.6* and *CGI* didn't install!

The dialog image:
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/9aAa48o.png]

```
The PHP Manager log: http://pastebin.com/Y9Ud1XUU

The WebPI log: http://pastebin.com/H13fJU0Z
```

I've tried setting the [MajorVersion to 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216228/php-manager-for-iis-fails-to-install) (and other values), but the installer still fails. I have .NET 4.5> installed.

Comment: A new release 2.0 is coming with IIS 10 support, https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know this addon/tool has not been working since the release of Windows Server 2012 R2.

i have still to find Another tool like it, but so far nothing has come up
though i have found this solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8

(confirmed to work, just remember to restart the IIS manager)

Comment: You should add some bits of information on how the link helps answering the question to your answer in case the mentioned link will be unavailable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Manager requires .NET Framework **3.5** installed and may require a small hack in the registry as outlined [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8):

> I was able to find a workaround at the [PHP manager's site](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/workitem/2653).
>   Just make sure you have .NET 3.5 installed and modify the following registry:
>
> ```
> HKLM/System/CCS/Services/W3SVC/Parameters/MajorVersion
> ```
>
> The value is 10 (Ax0). Just change the value to 9 (or 8), then try to install it again.
>
> To avoid future issues with other IIS stuff, change back to 10 (Ax0). It seems that PHP Manager validates the value converting it into string or something related.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows Server 2016 machine for some reason the Web Platform Installer (downloaded from https://php.iis.net/) gave me a less recent PHP version (5.3.28) than yours, but all components were correctly installed, with the exception of PHP Manager (which I was expecting given it has been discontinued, and I didn't really care anyway...):

[image]

Also, if you want, you can install the components manually, by following this detailed post:

[Steps to Install PHP manually on Windows 2016 server](https://www.assistanz.com/steps-to-install-php-manually-on-windows-2016-server/)

It's really not complicated and it will give you a better understanding of what is not working, should that be the case.

With the help of above article I could also verify that the Web Platform Installer did not miss any important parts (modifying php.ini as required by extensions, setting environment variables, and so on).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We have several Windows Server 2012 R2 servers with PHP Manager running without problems (sorry Robert). I have just setup a new one and added PHP Manager and others by installing PHP 5.6 with Web Platform installer. The only thing needed extra was .NET 3.5. Have you tried to setup with .NET 3.5 installed?

When you try to install PHP Manager using the direct download link, the setup will ask you to install .NET 2.0. That isn't necessary :).